# Why this CSS code doesn't work in IE 10 while working on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

[This code](http://jsfiddle.net/8Vu92/2/) works fine on Firefox and Chrome, but not on IE 10.
The blue part doesn't layout with proper size on the IE 10

I think the problem is with:

```
.main-scroll {
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-color: blue;
    border-style:solid;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

which its `height: 100%` seems not to work properly. As I know, all of used styles are valid in HTML 5.0 and CSS 3.0.

**Question:** So why this code doesn't work properly on IE 10 and what's the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set #body to relative position

```
#body {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    position:relative;/*so that the children can habe an absolute position*/
}
```

and then

```
.main-scroll {
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-color: blue;
    border-style:solid;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8Vu92/3/

i dont know what you are trying to do but if you just want the color blue and red you can use box-shadow

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8Vu92/4/

```
<section class="main">
    This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content.
</section>
```

the css

```
.main {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
    border:4px solid blue;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 4px red;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**UPDATE: using transform**

```
#body {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
.shell {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-color: red;
    border-style:solid;
}

.header-row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 40px
}
.main-row {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
    border-style:solid;
}
.main-scroll {
    height:120px;
    width: 100%;
    border-color: blue;
    border-style:solid;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    transform:translate3d(0,30px,0);
}
.main {
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

markup:

```
<div id="body">
    <div class="shell">
        <div class="header-row">
            This is the fixed height header
        </div>
        <div class="main-row">
            <div class="main-scroll">
                <section class="main">This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content. This is the content.</section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/8Vu92/8/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The coloring is just for clarification! Your first solution seems OK, but changing those positioning values are not possible due some other considerations which I haven't mentioned in the fiddle. Is there another solution other than changing positions?

Comment: The problem is that there's another header row with fixed height. changing the position to absolute corrupts the sizing. As the first row is going to have a fixed height, and the second row is going to fill the remaining area.

Comment: This is the link of your solution, mixed with the new row: http://jsfiddle.net/8Vu92/6/

Comment: ok so you wnat me to remove the position absolute and relative from this fiddle (NEW from you) and find a way to habe the same result without using position relative or absolute ?

Comment: Yep, That would be great.

Comment: In jsfiddle.net/8Vu92/7 you've fixed the height instead of setting it by percent. But the height should be declared by percent so it can fit to page on re-sizing for responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

```
.main-scroll {
    position: relative;
    border-color: blue;
    border-style:solid;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

try this in IE

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want fixed sizing due to my situation.